# Create a RAR archive for each subdirectory in a directory - Centos/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, rar

If using RAR on Ubuntu or Centos, this is the command for compressing a single folder (with subfolders inside), or is the command for compressing all folders inside a directory in a single archive:

```
rar a -m0 -r name.rar
```

where

**-m0** is level of compression
**-r** recursive mode

But if I want to compress each folder? Which commands to use?

I want preserve the directory tree on compressing each folder.

I tried also this command,

```
for folder in */; do echo rar a -m0 -r "${folder%/}.rar" "$folder"; done
```

but it gave me no action, but in terminal appears so:

```
user@hppro ~
$ ls -l
total 3
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user None  0 Aug  2 03:17 abcd_dir
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 user None  0 Aug  2 03:18 defgh_dir
-rwx------  1 user None 86 Dec 24  2020 blahfile

user@hppro ~
$ for folder in */; do echo rar a -m0 -r "${folder%/}.rar" "$folder"; done
rar a -m0 -r abcd_dir.rar abcd_dir/
rar a -m0 -r defgh_dir.rar defgh_dir/

user@hppro ~
$
```

The parameter substitution `${folder%/}` serves to strip out the "/" at the end of the folder name. But this code does not work.

Source: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/compress-folder-in-rar-652612/

P.S: I use Centos or Ubuntu not Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably just need to remove `echo`:

```
for folder in */; do rar a -m0 -r "${folder%/}.rar" "$folder"; done
```